# Reporting Services Line Graph: How to better control the smoothed curve

Tags: .net, graphics, reporting-services, charts, splines

I have a report that I built for a client where I need to plot x 0-100, y 0-100. Let's imagine I have these points:

```
   0,  0
  2,  24
 50,  70
100, 100
```

I need to represent these as a smoothed line chart, as the application of it is a dot gain graph for printing presses.

Here's the problem. The line draws fine from 100,100 (top right) down to 2,24. But then what happens is from 2,24 to 0,0 the line curves out off the left of the graph and then to down to 0,0. Imagine it putting a point at -10,10.

I understand this is because of the generic [Bézier curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve) algorithm it is using and the large separation of control points, thus heavily weighting it.

I was wondering however if anyone knows a way I can control it. I have tried adding in averaged points between the existing control points, but it still curves off the graph as if it's still heavily weighted.

The only other answer I can think of is custom drawing a graph or looking into [Dundas Charts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dundas_Data_Visualization#History) and using its [GDI+](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_Device_Interface#Windows_XP) drawing support.

But before I go that route, anyone have any thoughts?

---

Here's the thing. I know how to draw the curve manually. The problem lies in the fact that there is such a high weighting between 2 and 50. I tried to add points in at the lows and the mids, but it was still bowing off the edge. I will have to go check out the source and modify the graph back and see if I can get a screenshot up.

Right now I just have the graph stop at 2 until I can get this solved.

Answer (score 2):

[alt text http://img140.imageshack.us/img140/1279/smoothlinebezierxl0.jpg](http://img140.imageshack.us/img140/1279/smoothlinebezierxl0.jpg)

(Providing a picture of the behaviour to help you get a better answer).

For those with a theory, you can try this out in Excel as well (not just Reporting Services).

You mentioned adding points in your question, but it seems like adding in interpolated points near the problem area has the desired effect (e.g. { (1,12), (1.5, 18) }). This is a clumsy "solution" at best though.

Comment: The image link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a cosine interpolation for the points in-between.